# Electron Navigation (Single-page navigation)

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm using electron to build a single-page application that has a drop down menu for navigation. The number of pages in the application is dynamic and based on the data in a JSON object that I have. I searched the web for good ways to do this but I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how I can do navigation with a drop down menu for a dynamic number of pages. For example, if my JSON object required having two pages I would need the drop down to have two options (page1, page2). The app starts with page1 and once I click on the dropdown and select page2 the screen switches to that page. This has to be extensible for n number of pages.

I'm desperate for solutions and I feel like the documentation/resources for navigation like this in Electron is lacking.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is what you're saying that you don't want the page to navigate away when you click an option in your dropdown? I'm still confused on what you want, but from the description would having some JS or Jquery that adds or removes content on the page when you click an item in the dropdown work?

Comment: I need to have a drop down menu that handles navigation between screens. I don't want multiple screens; I want the same screen to change when I select a new option on the drop down (hence single page). When I talked about dynamic options think about my dataset having a length of 2. I would then need two options in my dropdown one for page1 and one for page2 (it initially loads page1 with the data from element 0 in the array). Each page would have the same layout though so that simplifies things. They just would have different data in the static layout. Let me know if this helps clarify.

Comment: Is this dropdown a HTML dropdown or an Electron menu list? It sounds like this isn't an Electron issue, but more a front-end design issue. With these sorts of things it's better to try your best on your own. If you're not sure where to start, try creating a small HTML test case first - seprate from Electron.

Comment: I'd guess it's more of an HTML dropdown menu so I'll try myself first. I'd rather not have the navigation be in the Electron Menu Bar.

Comment: I created a small example to get you started: https://gist.github.com/Mike-Wood/1aa4fb3c4b56c525148b41a88380c0f0

Comment: @Joshua I'll check it out thanks for helping!